# JPA + hibernate foreign key is null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables in my database. I have got a Project which can have multiple builds. One build belongs to one project. Everything works fine, except the foreign key in my build table remains null.

Project

```
@Entity(name="project")
public class Project implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "projectID")
private Long id;

@Column
@JsonProperty("displayName")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("builds")
@JsonIgnore
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = ("project"))
private Collection<Build> builds;

public Project() {
}

public Project(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Collection<Build> getBuilds() {
    return builds;
}

public void setBuilds(Collection<Build> builds) {
    this.builds = builds;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
}
```

Build

```
@Entity(name = "build")
public class Build implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column
@JsonProperty("number")
private Integer number;

@Column
@JsonProperty("url")
private String url;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "project")
private Project project;

public Build() {
}

public Build(String url, Project project, Integer number) {
    this.url = url;
    this.project = project;
    this.number = number;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
}
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: please attach the code in which you persist your entities

Answer (score 1):

Using JPA you need explicitly define the `Project` in your `Build` object.

```
Project project = new Project();

Build build = new Build();
build.setProject(project);

project.setBuilds(Collections.singletonList(build));

// now you can persist it    
em.persist(project)
```

From Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir):

> First, keep in mind that Hibernate does not affect normal Java
>   semantics. How did we create a link between a Person and an Event in
>   the unidirectional example? You add an instance of Event to the
>   collection of event references, of an instance of Person. If you want
>   to make this link bi-directional, you have to do the same on the other
>   side by adding a Person reference to the collection in an Event. This
>   process of "setting the link on both sides" is absolutely necessary
>   with bi-directional links.